# Uses of integral calculus in discrete mathematics?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, soft-question, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I have to do a project in my integral calculus class. But all the topics are too mainstream (parabolic arc calculation,archimedean approzimation of circle are,obtaining $E=mc^2\dots$

However I'm really into discrete maths right now and I would like to use integral calculus for my project in discrete mathematics?

Is this viable? What are some topics I could persue?(Things I am really into right now are combinatorial identities, graph theory,abstract algebra and category theory).

Thank you very much in advance, forgive me if this question is innapropriate.

Best Wishes.

Comment: If you cook up a function with the correct residues at the integers, you can use Cauchy's residue theorem to compute infinite sums. For example $(\pi \cot \pi z) / z^2$ has has residue $- \pi^2 / 3$ at the origin and residues $1/n^2$ at $\pm n$, so considering the square $\pm (n + 1/2) \pm \mathrm{i}(n + 1/2)$ you get $\sum_{n \ge 1} 1/n^2 = \pi^2 / 6$

Comment: You can often approximate the number of lattice points in a region by calculating the volume of the region. A famous example of this as in "Gauss' circle problem" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem . It seems to me that many combinatorial problems can be reduced to computing lattice points which in turn can be approximated into volumes (which is mentioned above). Also see http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/papers/noprint.pdf . Also, The theory of integer partitions uses some heavy duty analysis see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with Discrete Fourier Transform . The term Fourier Transform , used in Applied Sciences and Engineering , is actually Fourier Integral .